# Select multiple categories from one input field in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to select multiple categories in one input field, I have a code, but it is not working:

**PostController**:

```
foreach($request->category_id as $key => $value) {
  Project::create([
     'name' => $request->name,
     'body' => $request->body,
     'category_id' => $request->category_id[$key],
  ]);
}
```

**Form**:

```
<select name="category_id[]" id="category_id" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-success btn-round" data-live-search="true" data-size="5" multiple>
   @foreach($categories as $category)
   <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried `select2` jquery plugin for multiple-select? Coding is easier with packages and plugins! Popular, Reusable, Constructive, Logical, Less-buggy, Robust codes for free!!!

Comment: I don't need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have one Post in multiple categories, you need to change your Database also.
You cant have only one category_id in `posts` table.

You have to adapt Many To Many relationship (One Post can be in multiple categories, one Category can have multiple Posts).

More here: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Than you can save it simple with one line (based on your code):

```
$post->categories()->sync($request->category_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in PostController

```
foreach($request->category_id as $value) {
  Project::create([
     'name' => $request->name,
     'body' => $request->body,
     'category_id' => $value,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: It makes two same post, I want one post to have two or more categories

Comment: ok then you should use many to many relationship